# Who do these helmets belong to?

Tags: movie, comics, character-identification

A recent image presented by none other than [SQB](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/107023) in Mos has arisen, and it's my turn to post.  There's a [shirt](http://www.bustedtees.com/moviehelmets) currently available on Busted Tees which features several helmets from the SFF genre. Unfortunately, not all of them are easy to identify...

**Whose helmets are these?**

[image: Img]

Comment: don't know that I'd consider Maximus SFF but hey - it's a cool rig

Comment: @NKCampbell Historical fantasy!

Comment: I got 12 out of 13, yay! :P

Comment: I remember a similar question previously, which had masks on a wall (including, e.g. Majora's Mask etc.) Does anyone know where that is, so that we can link these together.

Comment: "To whom do these masks belong?" http://pbfcomics.com/99/

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**Top row (L to R)**

- [The Rocketeer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rocketeer_(film))

  [image: Rocketeer]
- [Iron Man](http://marvel.com/universe/Iron_Man_(Anthony_Stark))

  [image: Iron Man]
- [Tron](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084827/)

  [image: Tron]
- Red Ranger (*[from Mighty Morphin Power Rangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Morphin_Power_Rangers)*)

  [image: Red Ranger]

**Center Row (L to R)**

- [Judge Dredd](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113492/)

  [image: Dredd]
- [Darth Vader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker) (from the *Star Wars* franchise)

  [image: Vader]
- [The Witch King of Angmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings) (from *The Lord of the Rings* films)

  [image: Witch King]
- [Boba Fett](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett) (from the *Star Wars* franchise)

  [image: Fett]
- [Maximus Decimus Meridius](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172495/) (from the film *Gladiator*)

  [image: Maximus]

**Bottom Row (L to R)**

- [Black Knight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071853/) (from the film *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*)

  [image: Black Night]
- [Robocop](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093870/)

  [image: Robocop]
- [Predator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_(franchise))

  [image: Predator]
- [Magneto](http://marvel.com/universe/Magneto_(Max_Eisenhardt)) (from the *X-Men* franchise)

  [image: Magneto]

Comment: It's [Boba Fett's helmet](http://img15.deviantart.net/cfab/i/2013/141/d/7/boba_fett_by_cwdigital-d66331e.jpg). [Jango's helmet](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/50845/screenshots/2398047/jangofett.jpg) doesn't have those little vertical stripes on it.

Comment: @Valorum I'm still disappointed that they aren't the same helmet.

Comment: For the record, that's not the helmet that the (Jungle Hunter) Predator wore in the Predator film, it's the one that the Predator wore in the appallingly bad AvP film.

Comment: Yeah, I thought Boba took his fathers armor?

Comment: @Skooba - He couldn't fit his head into the helmet for some reason..

Comment: @Valorum Queue the sad trumpet music

Comment: Only one I missed was Maximus Decimus Meridius which I thought was the headpiece of [MF DOOM](http://www.egotripland.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/MF-Doom-RBMA-Comic.jpg). I guess he must have taken it from Maximus

Comment: Haha!  A couple of them I got wrong but had the franchise right... (I guess Sauron and Thor)

Comment: @Valorum Aren't they clones? How does the head not fit?!

Comment: @Withywindle Yeah, sorry Gladiator, but I think MF DOOM's got you beat. He holds the mic and your attention like two swords, or maybe the one with two blades on it.

Comment: @Shane Because the space was already occupied.

Comment: @Shane he had [this](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/1/1e/Jangodied.JPG/revision/latest?cb=20111022201552) problem and ended like [this](http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/25100000/The-Death-of-Jango-Fett-Geonosis-star-wars-25114663-500-375.jpg).

Answer (score 20):

Going from Left to Right:

Top Row:

- The Rocketeer

  [image: Rocketeer]
- Iron Man
- Tron

  [image: Tron 80s]
- Red Power Ranger (*Mighty Morphin Power Rangers* series)

  [image: Red Ranger]

Center Row:

- Judge Dredd
- Darth Vader
- The Witch-King of Angmar (*The Lord of the Rings*)
- Mandalorian helmet, looks like Boba Fett's according to Valorum.
- Gladiator (*Gladiator*)

  [image: Russel Crowe, omg Russel Crowe])

Bottom Row:

- The Black Knight (*Monty Python and the Holy Grail*)
- Robocop
- Predator
- Magneto